# Can hibernate property be both persistent and calculated?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

Let's say I have a `Person` class with `dateOfBirth` and `yearOfBirth` properties, persisted in Postge database.
And I need to map `yearOfBirth` with condition: if `dateOfBirth` is set, than extract year from it, else use `yearOfBirth` value.

I tried to use mapping like this:

```
<property name="dateOfBirth" type="timestamp" >
    <column name="date_of_birth" />
</property>

<property name="yearOfBirth" type="integer" formula="(
              CASE
                WHEN dateofbirth is NULL THEN year_of_birth
                ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dateofbirth, 'YYYY'), 'FM9999')
              END
              )" generated="always">
        <column name="year_of_birth"/>
</property>
```

But it gave me PSQLException: `ERROR: column coreemploy0_.year_of_birth does not exist`. But column `year_of_birth` definitely exists in the table.

More than that, I tried to use simplified mapping:

```
<property name="yearOfBirth" type="integer" formula="(
               TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dateofbirth, 'YYYY'), 'FM9999')
              )" generated="always">
        <column name="year_of_birth"/>
</property>
```

It gave me correct output, but column in my database remained to be empty after an entity was updated. I thought `generated="always"` part should made the property updatable.

So, can anyone please tell, is there a correct way to make that property both calculated and persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Computed properties do not have a column mapping of their own.

Already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772702/hibernate-how-to-persist-a-property-which-is-mapped-with-formula)

Comment: So how do you think, would creating additional field to store year, say, `persistedYearOfBirth`, be correct way to solve this task? Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: You can try. But Is there real need to store it in the database? Think about it because persisting of this calculated property may be rather expensive. It can hurt your performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunately I have to store both birth year and birth date (cause not all users are willing to provide exact birth date). 

So I somehow need to have persisted property for the year (to provide users an opportunity to input it) and calculated property - for output and querying operations.